# How to set the action of UITableViewRowAction

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uitableviewrowaction

I customized my UITableCellDeleteConfirmationView to change the background color of the button in iOS 8 and above. [Following this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20290766/change-the-color-of-default-red-color-delete-button-in-uitableviewcell-when-swip), I implemented `editActionsForRowAtIndexPath`, `commitEditingStyle` and `canEditRowAtIndexPath`.

```
-(NSArray *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editActionsForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    RankedSpecies* rankedSpecies = [fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    if ( [self.collectedLeaf.selectedSpecies isEqualToString:[rankedSpecies.Species commonNameFirstLast]] )
    {
        UITableViewRowAction *unlabelSpecies = [UITableViewRowAction rowActionWithStyle:UITableViewRowActionStyleNormal title:@"UnLabel" handler:^(UITableViewRowAction *action, NSIndexPath *indexPath)
                                        {
                                             NSLog(@"Action to perform with Button 1");
                                        }];
        unlabelSpecies.backgroundColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];

        return @[unlabelSpecies];
    }

    UITableViewRowAction *labelSpecies = [UITableViewRowAction rowActionWithStyle:UITableViewRowActionStyleNormal title:@"Label" handler:^(UITableViewRowAction *action, NSIndexPath *indexPath)
                                    {
                                        NSLog(@"Action to perform with Button 1");
                                    }];
    labelSpecies.backgroundColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];

    return @[labelSpecies];
}
```

However, when I push these custom buttons, they do not call `commitEditingStyle`. [According to this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19389545/commiteditingstyle-is-not-fired), `commitEditingStyle` is only fired when you touch the delete button.

Instead of trying to figure out how to fire `commitEditingStyle`, I have created methods that replicate my `commitEditingStyle` implementation, `removeCollectedLeafLabel`. **Can a class method be an action? How do I set the UITableViewRowAction to do something when pressed?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when your press button it will call the block.

```
UITableViewRowAction *unlabelSpecies = [UITableViewRowAction rowActionWithStyle:UITableViewRowActionStyleNormal title:@"UnLabel" handler:^(UITableViewRowAction *action, NSIndexPath *indexPath)
                                        {
                                             CALL_YOUR_METHOD_FROM_HERE
                                        }];


unlabelSpecies.backgroundColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];

return @[unlabelSpecies];
```